# Print " (double quotation) using sprintf in R

Tags: r

How to print `"` around my text using `sprintf` in `R`?

**Example:**

```
Name<-"X"
sprintf({"%s"},Name)
```

which the output is:

```
[1] "X"
```

But I need

```
[1] ""X""
```

Comment: You need `sprintf('"%s"',Name)`  Check it with `cat` i.e. `cat(sprintf('"%s"',Name), "\n")`

Comment: @akrun, I need the "sprintf", Since I already made it using "cat"

Comment: @akrun 's point is you can check that `sprintf()` works by testing it with `cat()`, not that you should use `cat()` instead of `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is `shQuote` You can do

```
shQuote(Name)
# [1] "\"X\""
```

Note that R needs to escape the inner quotes in the console. It will not print out something that looks like `""X""`. But if you `cat` the values the slashes aren't there

```
cat(shQuote(Name))
# "X"
```

Comment: Thanks but No @MrFlick, I want to use the `sprintf` since I need to assign the output of `sprintf` to a variable. So I guess `cat` cannot be useful. Also, `shQuote(Name)` which is not correct.

Comment: @EsterSilva That doesn't make sense. you can assign the output of `shQuote` just like you can `sprintf`. What exactly are you trying to do with this value? Can you provide some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that demonstrates why you need to quote this string value so that possible solutions other than what you are expecting can be tested and shown to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if another option will help you. But you can consider it:

The option could be:

```
Name<-"X"
#> sprintf("'%s'",Name)
#[1] "'X'"
```